# How to prove Hahn-Banach separation theorem for $X^*\times \mathbb{R}$ version?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

The following theorem is taken from [Behrend's M-Structure and Banach-Stone Theorem](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540095330), page $3.$

> **Theorem** $0.1$: Let $X$ be Banach space and $K_1,K_2$ be nonempty convex subsets of $X^*\times \mathbb{R}$ ($X^*$ is provided with weak$^*$-topology).
>
> Suppose that $K_1\cap K_2=\emptyset$ and that $K_1$ is closed and $K_2$ is compact.
>
> Then there exists $x\in X, a,r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$p_1(x)+aa_1<r<p_2(x)+aa_2$$
>   for all $(p_1,a_1)\in K_1$ and $(p_2,a_2)\in K_2.$
>
> Note that $r>0$ if $(0,0)\in K_1$ and that $a>0$ if there exist $p\in X^*$ and $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_1<a_2, (p,a_1)\in K_1$ and $(p,a_2)\in K_2.$

Behrend stated that the theorem above follows from the following two facts:

$(1)$ (Hahn-Banach separation theorem) Every nonempty compact convex set in a locally convex Hausdorff space can be strictly separated from every disjoint nonempty closed convex set.

$(2)$ Continuous linear functionals on $(X^*,\text{weak}^*\text{-topology})$ are just the evaluation at the points of $X.$

...................................................................................................................................................................

The following is my attempt:

Clearly $X^*\times \mathbb{R}$ is locally convex.
Since $K_1$ is a closed convex set while $K_2$ is a compact convex set, by Hahn-Banach separation theorem, there exist scalars $r,s$ and a continuous linear functional $x^*$ on $X^*\times\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$x^*(p_1,a_1)<r<s<x^*(p_2,a_2)$$
for all $(p_1,a_1)\in K_1$ and $(p_2,a_2)\in K_2.$
However, I do not know how to proceed from here.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here it is important to know that the dual of $X^*\times\mathbb R$ (with $X^*$ given the weak$^*$-topology) is $X\times\mathbb R$, with the pairing
$$(x,\alpha)(p,\beta)=p(x)+\alpha\beta.$$
Indeed, for each $x\in X$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, the map
$$(p,\beta)\mapsto p(x)+\alpha\beta$$
from $X^*\times\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is continuous and linear, so $X\times\mathbb R\subset(X^*\times\mathbb R)^*$.
If $f\in(X^*\times\mathbb R)^*$, then the map $p\mapsto f(p,0)$ is weak$^*$-continuous, hence there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(p,0)=p(x)$ for all $p\in X^*$.  Since $\beta\mapsto f(0,\beta)$ is linear, there is some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(0,\beta)=\alpha\beta$ for all $\beta\in\mathbb R$.  By linearity, we have $f(p,\beta)=p(x)+\alpha\beta$ for all $(p,\beta)\in X^*\times\mathbb R$.  Thus $(X^*\times\mathbb R)^*=X\times\mathbb R$.

Thus, the linear functional you obtain from the Hahn-Banach theorem is of the form $(p,\beta)\mapsto p(x)+\alpha\beta$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, $x\in X$, and you obtain 
$$p_1(x)+\alpha\beta_1<r<s<p_2(x)+\alpha\beta_2$$
for all $(p_1,\beta_1)\in K_1$ and $(p_2,\beta_2)\in K_2$.  From here, it should be just be routine work to check the statements in the last paragraph. If you have any trouble with that, let me know and I will edit/expand.

Comment: Well, last part is just simple verification using the inequality. Thanks for proving that he inequality. I understand better now.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help!

Comment: By $(X^*\times\mathbb R)^*=X\times\mathbb R$, do you mean that there exists a bijection between the two sets without any structure preserving property (like homeomorphism or isometry)? Furthermore, how do you show that the map $(p,\beta)\mapsto p(x)+\alpha\beta$ is continuous?

Comment: Dear @Aweygan, can you help me with my question above?

Comment: Sorry, I got pinged then ignored it.  When I say that $(X^*\times\mathbb R)^*=X\times\mathbb R$ I mean the map taking $(x,\alpha)\in X\times\mathbb R$ to the map $(p,\beta)\mapsto p(x)+\alpha\beta$ in $(X^*\times\mathbb R)^*$ is a linear homeomorphism (so it preserves topological and linear structure).

Comment: And for your second question, note that each map $p\mapsto p(x)$ and $\beta\mapsto\alpha\beta$ is continuous (in the respective topological spaces), hence the map $(p,\beta)\mapsto(p(x),\alpha\beta)$ is continuous from $X^*\times\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$, and the map $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$.  Compose the last two maps.